# How do I get a custom radio button to check?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, radio-button

I am creating a custom form but have hit a snag: The Radio buttons; when you click on them in the unchecked status the do not check. They will check if click the associated Div and the will also uncheck when checked. I have tried to extend the JS to the Label and It still does not work. And so...

How do I get a custom radio button to check and/or what do i need to do to get this to function?

Here is the relevant Code:

```js
 function check(checkbox) {
   if (document.getElementById(checkbox).checked == false) {
     document.getElementById(checkbox).checked = true;
   } else {
     document.getElementById(checkbox).checked = false;
   }
 }
```

```css
 .title {
   display: inline;
   position: relative;
   top: 2px;
   font-family: "Arial";
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 18px;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   margin-left: 0px;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   font-stretch: ultra-condensed;
 }
 input[type="radio"] {
   display: none;
 }
 [type="radio"] + label {
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
 }
 [type="radio"] + label {
   background-color: #A3D5FF;
   border: 1px solid #A3D5FF;
   padding: 9px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   margin-right: 30px;
 }
 [type="radio"]:checked + label {
   background-color: #0088A8;
   ;
   border: 3px solid #fff;
   height: 5.75px;
   width: 5.75px;
   color: #243441;
 }
 input[type="radio"] + label {
   cursor: pointer;
   font-size: 1em;
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   right: -27px;
 }
 .chk {
   background: #009FC2;
   width: 265px;
   height: 30px;
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
 }
 .chk:hover {
   background: #0088A8;
 }
HTML
```

```html
<div class="chk" onClick="check('f-unlimited')">
  <h3 class="title">
                Unlimited  
              </h3>
  <input id="f-unlimited" name="format" type="radio" value="f-unlimited" checked="checked"></input>
  <label for="f-unlimited"></label>
</div>
<div class="chk" onClick="check('f-expandedFormat')">
  <h3 class="title">
                Expanded Format  
              </h3>
  <input id="f-expandedFormat" name="format" type="radio" value="f-expandedFormat"></input>
  <label for="f-expandedFormat"></label>
</div>
<div class="chk" onClick="check('f-standardLegal')">
  <h3 class="title">
                Standard Legal  
              </h3>
  <input id="f-standardLegal" name="format" type="radio" value="f-standardLegal"></input>
  <label for="f-standardLegal"></label>
</div>
</div>
```

Additional note: I am running almost identical code for my checkboxes and they are working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `check` function. When you click on the div it fires to reverse the check state. When you click the check itself, the check state is reversed, then the `check` function runs and reverses the state again. You need to cancel event propagation when the check itself is clicked.

Comment: With or without the JS in the radio label. The code does not work correctly.

Comment: If I comment out the contents of `check()` clicking the div won't check the radio, but clicking the radio will check it. Try binding another event to the radio buttons that includes `e.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: I added this:   ` function checkradio(checkbox) {
  if(document.getElementById(checkbox).checked == false) {
     document.getElementById(checkbox).checked = true;
  }
click.stopPropagation()
  }` and added the call to the div and the Input(radio). Worked like a charm. Thanks-@DunningKrugerEffect

Comment: If I may suggest: function check(checkbox)
{
 var el = document.getElementById(checkbox), btns = document.getElementsByName("format");
 for (var i=0;i<btns.length;i++) btns[i].checked=false;
 el.checked = !el.checked;
}
for 'true' Radio button functionality.

Answer (score 0):

noted, previous answer was in jquery, please see below for vanilla

javascript :

```
function checkboxClicked() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
}
function check(checkbox) { 
    if (document.getElementById(checkbox).checked == false) {
      document.getElementById(checkbox).checked = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(checkbox).checked = false;
    } 
  }
```

html :

```
    <div class="chk" onClick="check('f-unlimited')">
      <h3 class="title">
                    Unlimited  
                  </h3>
      <input onclick="checkboxClicked()" id="f-unlimited" name="format" type="radio" value="f-unlimited" checked="checked"></input>
      <label for="f-unlimited"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="chk" onClick="check('f-expandedFormat')">
      <h3 class="title">
                    Expanded Format  
                  </h3>
      <input onclick="checkboxClicked()" id="f-expandedFormat" name="format" type="radio" value="f-expandedFormat"></input>
      <label for="f-expandedFormat"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="chk" onClick="check('f-standardLegal')">
      <h3 class="title">
                    Standard Legal  
                  </h3>
      <input onclick="checkboxClicked()" id="f-standardLegal" name="format" type="radio" value="f-standardLegal"></input>
      <label for="f-standardLegal"></label>
    </div>
```

Comment: The Javascript used in the question is vanilla and not jQuery, so this would add additional overhead